# If $f(x) >0$ for all $x$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I met a problem like this:

Suppose $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ , and also that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists.

a) Show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ge 0$.

b) Give an example where $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$.

I am not sure how to solve it.. in fact I have no idea.
Could anyone give me a hint？
Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you mean the original function to be $f(x)\ge 0$?

Comment: @AdamHrankowski It wouldn't affect the conclusion.

Comment: Suppose the limit is $ L <0$. If I give you $\epsilon = |L|/2$, can you give me $\delta$?

Comment: The question is about the original function, f(x) is always greater than 0 for all x. also, lim x-a f(x) exists, say lim x→a f(x) = L. We want to prove that L is  ≥ 0

Comment: $\ge$ would make b) trivial, so it probably does mean $>$.

Comment: @BenMillwood Good point.

Comment: Or you can use the definition of limit to show that $L \ge -\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon.$

Comment: a) Let $L$ be the limit. If $L=0$ you're done. Otherwise, same hint as @AndréNicolas: let $e = |L| / 2$, so the interval $(L-e, L+e)$ doesn't contain 0. Because the limit exists, there's $d>0$ such that $f$ maps $(a-d, a+d) \text{ minus } \{a\}$ into  $(L-e, L+e)$. So all those values of $f$ must be on the same side of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be the limit, you wish to show: $L \geq 0$. You could prove this directly, but most "students" would choose the indirect proof. So assume $L < 0$.Thus choose $\epsilon = \dfrac{-L}{4} > 0$, then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \dfrac{-L}{4} \Rightarrow f(x) - L \leq |f(x)-L| < \dfrac{-L}{4} \Rightarrow f(x) < L-\dfrac{L}{4}= \dfrac{3L}{4} < 0$, contradiction. Thus $L \geq 0$. An example of such a function is $f(x) =  e^{-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}, x \neq 0$,and  $1, x = 0$ has $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)= 0$

Comment: Thank you so much, ! think that's a great answer!